# How to persist a mounted checkbox value to the server/database with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Building an app w/ Vue.js and Laravel for the server/API.

I have a list of `collaborators` where each `collaborator` has a boolean property for `edit_access` that are displayed on the page like so:

```js
<ul v-for='collaborator in collaborators' :key='collaborator.id'>            
    <li>
        @{{ collaborator.email }}
        <input type='checkbox' v-model='collaborator.edit_access'>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I've used `v-model` on the checkbox, so the user can toggle the edit access for the given collaborator.

My question is: what is the best way to persist changes to the checkbox (i.e. `edit_access`) to the database?

Do I add a `v-on` listener to the checkboxes that fires an ajax call to the server?

That's how I would have handled it using jquery, but it feels imperative and not a very "vue.js" way of doing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right. You can add `<input type='checkbox' v-model='collaborator.edit_access' @change="method_to_call(item_id)">`

Then in method `method_to_call(item_id)` make ajax request (I recommend to use axios with Vue.js) and update the value on the server in your database.

**Example**

```
<ul v-for='(collaborator,index) in collaborators' :key='collaborator.id'>            
    <li>
        @{{ collaborator.email }}
        <input type='checkbox' v-model='collaborator.edit_access' @change="method_to_call(index)">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then in methods

```
methods:{
  method_to_call(index){
     let collaborator = this.collaborators[index];
     // you  have collaborator id, edit_access, e.t.c.
     // send data to server and update in the database 
  }
.......
}
```

Comment: Another way I thought to do it would be to set up a watcher. What would be the pros/cons of that vs. @change?

Comment: `@change` method calling when the value of checkbox, using a method in v-for with id `<input type='checkbox' v-model='collaborator.edit_access' @change="method_to_call(index,collaborator.id)">` you also access the value and the id, and you can update it immidiatly. Using a watcher for finding where the change is happend in your collection is a bad idea, because it is very resource intensive compared to the previous one, where you immedialtly acess the index and the id (or only the index is enough for access the data from the array )